# $u^3+v^3+3^{5}w^3=2\cdot3^{2}uvw$ has no non- trivial solutions if $u,v,w$ are pairwise co-prime.

Tags: diophantine-equations

Let $u,v,w$ be 3 pairwise coprime integers. Then $$u^3+v^3+3^{5}w^3=2\cdot3^{2}uvw$$ has no non-trivial solutions. How can I prove this?

I have tried to consider many individual cases such as $uvw>0$,$uvw<0$, $max(u,v,w)=u$ etc. a pretty tedious approach. I am certain there must be simpler ones. Any hints?

Comment: Here is a simple case, $u>0, v>0, w>0$. Then $$u^3+v^3+243w^3 \ge 3 \sqrt[3]{243}uvw>18uvw$$ By AM-GM inequality.

Comment: I agree. However, there are quite a few other cases to consider.

Comment: It may be difficult.

Comment: i agree. Hence, my question.

Comment: I could not find this in Dickson's history of the theory of numbers.

Comment: Why the co-primality restriction? A quick computer search does not even reveal _any_ solution other than $u=-v$.

Comment: That's correct. the only solutions are $(1,-1,0); (-1,1,0)$. I am trying to figure out why. It seems like it has to do with the size of  $3^5w^3$

Answer (score 1):

$$  u = 1,  \; \; v = -1, \; \; w = 0  $$

Comment: my apologies. I edited the question.

Comment: @NumThcurious for a homogeneous function in integers, non-trivial means at least one variable nonzero. It really does. So, where did you get the problem?

Answer (score 1):

$u = -v, w = 0$.

Generalizing Will Jagy's.

Don't think that
either of these helps much.

Comment: My apologies, I meant no non-trivial solutions. I edited the question.